# How to hide BottomNavigationBar when scrolling?

Tags: android, xml, material-design, bottomnavigationview

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/activityMain_fragmentContainerView_container"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:defaultNavHost="true" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/activityMain_bottomNavigationView_bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**home_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.HomeFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".fragments.HomeFragment">

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/fragmentHome_materialTextView_titleOfCategories"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1500dp"
            android:text="Categories"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Inside `FragmentContainerView` I'm showing `home_fragment.xml` and inside this fragment, I can scroll down.

I'm trying when I scroll down in `home_fragment.xml` want to hide the `BottomNavigationView` and show it when scrolling up.

I tried to put `app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior"` but it does not have any effect.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `BottomNavigationView` directly in your CoordinatorLayout so your behavior will work ;)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75824712/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).